# Accessing custom property of hostComponent when skinning - Flex 4.5, SDK 4.5

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, skinning

Using SDK 4.1 I was able to access custom properties of a custom button component from a custom skin. The project I'm currently working requires SDK 4.5 and I'm unable to to access the properties. Here's an example:

**Custom Button Component**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ButtonBase xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          skinClass="components.skins.ButtonIcon_Skin"
          >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:String id="iconCustom" />
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:ButtonBase>
```

**Custom Button Skin**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
             minWidth="21" minHeight="21" 
             alpha.disabled="0.5">
    <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("components.ButtonIcon")]</fx:Metadata>

...

    <s:Label id="test" {hostComponent.iconCustom}" 
             horizontalCenter="0" bottom="10" />

</s:SparkButtonSkin>
```

The code hint shows `hostComponent.iconCustom` but then gives the error :

```
Access of possibly undefined property iconCustom through a reference with static type spark.components.supportClasses:ButtonBase. ButtonIcon_Skin.mxml
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just replace that SparkButtonSkin with a regular Skin and you'll be just fine:

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("components.ButtonIcon")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="down" />
        <s:State name="over" />
        <s:State name="up" />
    </s:states>

    <s:Label text="test {hostComponent.iconCustom}" 
             horizontalCenter="0" bottom="10" />

</s:Skin>
```

Comment: you are a diamond. Worked a treat.

Comment: Using `<s:SparkSkin/>` also removed compile errors. However, I'm finding both solutions don't display the image I've set in the button bar (while `<s:SparkButtonSkin/>` preserves this image. Not sure why).

Comment: Why?  There's no why here.  What if I need `SparkButtonSkin` or something?  Can we get more clarification?  I know the answer's old, but that's what we do here isn't it?

Comment: @deltree I haven't done any Flex dev for years now, so I'm afraid I won't be able to provide you with an exact reason why anymore. I guess it must be some inheritance issue in the skin class hierarchy.

Comment: @ggkmath the whole point of creating a custom skin is to re-implement the visual aspect. You just add an image in there that binds to `iconCustom` and you're done. If your goal is just to restyle the original Spark skins a bit, you should use CSS instead.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, if you want to use SparkButtonSkin, just cast to your actual hostComponent

```
(hostComponent as ButtonIcon).iconCustom
```

or in context:

**Custom Button Skin**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
             minWidth="21" minHeight="21" 
             alpha.disabled="0.5">
    <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("components.ButtonIcon")]</fx:Metadata>

...

    <s:Label id="{(hostComponent as ButtonIcon).iconCustom}" 
             horizontalCenter="0" bottom="10" />

</s:SparkButtonSkin>
```

Comment: If I add this cast, the compile error goes away but is replaced with the warning "Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "hostComponent".  I can run with this warning, but the values I get from the hostComponent properties are invalid.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer Tommy. RIAstar's didn't work for me, as I required SparkButtonSkin somehow to show images. Your answer worked.