# How to access a custom ButtonBar button?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I've created a custom Spark ButtonBar. I'd like to show notification badges in it (i.e. a number showing how many notifications that tab has), but I can't figure out how to access the button externally.

I've looked at questions like this one: [Hide a Button in a ButtonBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476085/hide-a-button-in-a-buttonbar)

But that doesn't seem to work, the object I get back from:

> btnBarNav.dataGroup.getElementAt(0);

is not an instance of Button or my skin, it's a "GameMenuBarInnerClass0".

Any suggestions on how best to pass some data to my skin to show a number related to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to access and manipulate the view (your Buttons) directly. Use a model + data binding instead.

### Create a custom skin

Looks like you already did this, but just for reference: you'll need a custom skin for ButtonBar, and three skins for the ButtonBarButtons: one for the first button, one for the last and one that will apply to all buttons in between.

### Use presentation models for dataprovider

Create a presentation model that holds a label for the button, perhaps an icon and whatever additional information you'll require in the button. For example:

```
class ButtonModel {
    public var label:String;
    [Bindable]
    public var messageCount:int = 0;
}
```

Note that I made `messageCount` bindable so that we can bind to it later.

### Assign a collection of these models as dataprovider of the ButtonBar

```
<s:ButtonBar>
    <s:ArrayList>
        <rs:ButtonModel label="Button 1"/>
        <rs:ButtonModel label="Button 2"/>
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:ButtonBar>
```

### Use presentation properties in the custom skin

In your custom button skin, you can now bind to the properties of this presentation model. The hostcomponent (ButtonBarButton) has a property `data` that holds this model instance.

```
<s:Label id="labelDisplay"/>
<s:Label text="{hostComponent.data.messageCount}"/>
```

Whenever you update the `messageCount` property on the model, it will automatically be reflected in the button.

Comment: Thanks! I had originally tried something like this but couldn't get it to work because Flex complained that hostComponent didn't have a property "data". Another stackoverflow question gave me the hint that my skin had to be a generic <s:Skin> not a <s:SparkButtonSkin>

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268281/accessing-custom-property-of-hostcomponent-when-skinning-flex-4-5-sdk-4-5/6268635#6268635